# Clock signal sharpness

Tags: signal, pulse, termination

I'm currently tuning the termination resistors in the clock circuit.
[image]

The resistor here is 330 ohms, I got a rippled clock signal like this:
[image]

I increased both resistors value to 430 ohms and I got:
[image]

The ripples decreased but it became less of a square wave and more of a sine wave. Should I increase the resistor value to 530 ohms or do I decrease it to...?

Comment: First, check how you are measuring the signal.  You should be using at least a 10:1 probe that is properly compensated; with the ground wire being no more than 1/4" (6mm) long.  I normally wrap 2 or 3 turns of bare buss wire around the exposed shield at the front of the probe, twist tightly, cut as short as possible to reach the closes ground point, then solder to that ground.  Only then can you be reasonable certain of getting a good waveform.

Comment: It is possible that your probe is affecting the signal, as Dwayne says. Also, where are you probing? Between the source and the buffer or between the buffer and the FPGA? If you decide to tune the resistors, you should tune them separately. Subjectively both of your captures potentially look OK, but you want to check that the ringing amplitude (which could be a measurement artifact) doesn't cause double-clocking, and on the 43 Ohm capture see if the receiver has any rise and fall time constraints you might be violating.

Comment: Additionally you don't say what scope you are using, it might not have enough bandwidth